# Are surfaces (equivalent to) continuous maps from rectangles?

Tags: surfaces

Curves are continuous maps from an interval to a topological space. So a natural question is: is there any surface whose image is not the image of a continuous surjection from a rectangle to a topological space?  Wikipedia's page about surfaces says "(...) there are surfaces for which there cannot exist a single parametrization that covers the whole surface." but doesn't give any example...

Comment: the 2-sphere is an example

Comment: @janmarqz how to prove that? that would answer this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4062600/881385